# "more" command in perl

Tags: perl

Is there way to use the `more` command in a perl script? There is a file and I want to print its content, but since there are lots of lines I would like to print it with `more` . I tried putting `more` in backticks, but it didn't work:

```
open(FILE,'/opt/myfile' ) or die("Could not open  file.");
`more /opt/myfile`;
```

Comment: I would skip the perl and use [less](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/less.html), less is more! Read the first paragraph on the link, less is much better at reading large files.

Comment: You could make use of [`Term::Pager`](https://metacpan.org/module/Term::Pager), I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the system command:

```
system('more thefile');
```

Comment: `system('more', 'thefile')` is preferable, because it doesn't invoke a shell. (See my answer for why.)

Answer (score 6):

`` `more /opt/myfile` `` means to capture the output of the `more` command into a string, which is discarded (you'd usually store the output in a variable or pass it to a function). When its output is not connected to a terminal, `more` is equivalent to `cat`, it doesn't do anything useful.

To run a subprocess in Perl without capturing its output, use the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function.

```
system('more', '/opt/myfile');
```

Note that you should pass a list containing the command and its arguments, not a mere string. If you pass a single string to `system`, it is passed to a shell, which will expand any special character in the file name. For example, `system('more /opt/myfile')` would work but `system('more /opt/$(rm -rf ~)')` would delete all your files. If you pass multiple arguments, no shell is involved: `system('more', '/opt/$(rm -rf ~)')` invokes `more` on that strangely-named file.

If there's any risk that the file name begins with a `+` or `-`, pass `--` before the file name, to avoid having it interpreted as an option.

Rather than call `more`, you should check the `PAGER` environment variable, and call that if it is defined. `$PAGER` is the de facto standard pager. If the variable is not defined, in this millennium, you should default to `less` (if you're paranoid, default to `less` if it's present and `more` otherwise).

```
my $pager = $ENV{PAGER};
if (!defined $pager || $pager eq '') {
    $pager = 'less';
}
system($pager, '--', '/opt/myfile');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably open a pipe to the pager, something like this:

```
open(FILE, "/opt/myfile") or die("Could not open file.");
open(PIPE, "| more") or die("Could not open pipe"); 

while(<FILE>) {
  print PIPE;
}

close P;    
close FILE;'
```

Comment: more will not page the content of the file but will just output the whole standard input to standard output

Comment: It pages the output here, under which circumstances did you test it?